# ListPreference с Radiobuttons

Tags: java, android

в моей App есть 2 URL адреса:

```
   private static final String URL = "https://android.net.com/";   
   private static final String URL = "https://android.rest.net.com/";
```

сделал окно с Radiobuttons ,при помощи  ListPreference
 я хочу выбрать  из списка настроек, адресс который хочу использовать,как мне это сделать?

Comment: А как вы уже пробовали это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Если кратко - в PreferenceActivity сохраняйте выбранный вариант в SharedPreferences, а перед тем как сделать запрос (ну или зачем вам там эти адреса нужны) - достаньте из SharedPreferneces сохранённое значение, которое и будет соответствовать одному из этих адресов. Если нужно подробнее объяснить - сигнализируйте.

Comment: не могу понять как мне  присоединить адреса к RaioButon если можно не много поподробнее. за ранее благодарю

Comment: @TestingMan пользуйтесь константами. Ассоциируйте их с адресами. Пример: при выборе первого радиобаттона сохраняйте в SharedPreferences 0x01, при выборе второго радиобаттона - 0x02. Затем, когда понадобится использовать какой-то адрес, чтобы узнать какой - вы проверите значение сохранённой константы. Если 0х01 - доставайте свой первый адрес и используйте его, если 0x02 - соответственно используйте второй. Константам лучше дать осмысленные имена, но это уже вопросы изящности кода.

Comment: спасибо разобрался